# Ceiling LED recessed light installation gone wrong

Tags: light-fixture, ceiling, recessed-lighting

My contractor installed a recessed ceiling LED light. The metal box that comes with the light (pictures attached), he just kept it on the dry ceiling, covered by insulation cotton material. I am worried that it might heat up and catch fire to insulation material. Can someone look into the picture and tell if this is a proper installation?

[Link to installation pictures](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1vVDVZbAt_BPedMSIP-0qXA0C-_xdBoQM?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The insulation isn't the problem, the box won't heat up. The connections are the problem. Those large cables have to be secured into the box with proper connectors and the splices inside the box and the cover snapped closed. I'd get the contractor back to fix it. Not sure where you're at on this planet but I don't think that would be acceptable anywhere. If you have the instructions for the lights, you'll see the proper installation.